# Blackberry JDE 6 & 7 installation issue

Tags: blackberry, installation, java, prerequisites

I downloaded Blackberry JDE 6 and 7 from the site https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/previousjdeversions/

After downloading when I try to install, both 6 and 7 have same problem.  I have restarted my pc, but still no solution.

This is what happens:

In the prerequisite section it shows 3 text boxes

1. Name - Version - Action
   JDK - Required 1.5 or higher found 1.6 1.6.0_26 - **Skip**
2. Direct X - Required 4.08 found 4.09.00.0904 - **Skip**
3. Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86) - Required any Found nothing - **install**

Now by default Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86) is checked when I click **Next**, it extracts the package and status shows as installed but at the bottom of screen it shows error with message **"After launching all packages some required prerequisites are still missing, Press back button to return to prerequisites"**

when I click **back** button it goes back to the prerequisites page with checkboxes showing JDK Direct X and Microsoft Visual C++ and clicking **Next** has the same problem- shows installed but with error message

When I check the other two, for JDK and Direct X it opens browser with two tabs, one with oracle for jdk download, and the other with Microsoft Direct X

After I click **Next** it does the same as before, by extracting package for Microsoft Visual C++ and status shows as installed but at the bottom of screen it shows error with message **"After launching all packages some required prerequisites are still missing, Press back button to return to prerequisites"**

In my friend's computer, it installed fine and launched the BlackBerry emulator, both my friends and my computer runs windows 7.

Comment: Send an email to devsupport@rim.com

Comment: Thanks will do that, I just wanted to know if anyone had faced this issue and solved it..

Comment: Hi I tried that, I got a reply mail stating its for paid users, and pointed to forums, for free support..

Comment: That's strange. Before RIM used to help developers who requested help via this email address. Post your question here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev

Comment: @Rafael Osipov Lately they are ignoring even paid users. The Java APIs Developer Issue Tracker seems dead as well.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the serious problems RIM experience now.